# Best way in JavaScript to "intersect" two arrays of JSON objects by common property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Let's say we have two arrays, `arr1` and `arr2`, of JSON objects that share a common property `id`:

```
var arr1 = [{'id':10,'value1':'a1'},
            {'id':11,'value1':'b1'},
            {'id':12,'value1':'c1'},
            {'id':13,'value1':'d1'},
            {'id':14,'value1':'e1'}];

var arr2 = [{'id':100000,'value2':'a2'},
            {'id':11,'value2':'b2'},
            {'id':100002,'value2':'c2'},
            {'id':100003,'value2':'d2'},
            {'id':14,'value2':'e2'}];
```

I need to extract the "value" items from both arrays where the IDs match, i.e. the expected output would be:

```
[0] value1: b1, value2: b2
[1] value1: e1, value2: e2
```

I have a working sample of a nested-loop solution (see below), but it's slow (imagine these arrays being large and some UI operations involved for each iteration), so I really hope there is a more elegant and quicker solution for this.

```js
var arr1 = [{'id':10,'value1':'a1'},
            {'id':11,'value1':'b1'},
            {'id':12,'value1':'c1'},
            {'id':13,'value1':'d1'},
            {'id':14,'value1':'e1'}];

var arr2 = [{'id':100000,'value2':'a2'},
            {'id':11,'value2':'b2'},
            {'id':100002,'value2':'c2'},
            {'id':100003,'value2':'d2'},
            {'id':14,'value2':'e2'}];

for (var i = 0, len1 = arr1.length; i < len1; i++) {
 for (var j = 0, len2 = arr2.length; j < len2; j++) {
  if (arr1[i].id === arr2[j].id) {
   theFunction(arr1[i].value1, arr2[j].value2);
   break;
  }
 }
}

function theFunction(value1, value2) {
  var div = document.getElementById('out');
  div.innerHTML += '<br />value1: ' + value1 + ', value2: ' + value2;
}
```

```html
<div id='out'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build up a map of `id` to `value1` and then iterate over `arr2` matching them up:

```js
var arr1 = [{'id':10,'value1':'a1'},
            {'id':11,'value1':'b1'},
            {'id':12,'value1':'c1'},
            {'id':13,'value1':'d1'},
            {'id':14,'value1':'e1'}];

var arr2 = [{'id':100000,'value2':'a2'},
            {'id':11,'value2':'b2'},
            {'id':100002,'value2':'c2'},
            {'id':100003,'value2':'d2'},
            {'id':14,'value2':'e2'}];

var value1s = {};

arr1.forEach(function(item) {
  value1s[item.id] = item.value1;
});

arr2.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.id in value1s) {
    theFunction(value1s[item.id], item.value2);
  }
});

function theFunction(value1, value2) {
  var div = document.getElementById('out');
  div.innerHTML += '<br />value1: ' + value1 + ', value2: ' + value2;
}
```

```html
<div id='out'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might first build simple arrays of `id`, then work with them more simply, like this:

```js
var arr1 = [{'id':10,'value1':'a1'},
            {'id':11,'value1':'b1'},
            {'id':12,'value1':'c1'},
            {'id':13,'value1':'d1'},
            {'id':14,'value1':'e1'}];

var arr2 = [{'id':100000,'value2':'a2'},
            {'id':11,'value2':'b2'},
            {'id':100002,'value2':'c2'},
            {'id':100003,'value2':'d2'},
            {'id':14,'value2':'e2'}];

var tmp1 = arr1.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.id;
});
var tmp2 = arr2.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.id;
});
tmp1.forEach(function(id1, index1) {
  var index2 = tmp2.indexOf(id1);
  if (index2 > -1) {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML +=
      '<br />value1: ' + arr1[index1].value1 + 
      ', value2: ' + arr2[index2].value2;
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='out'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works really well -- about the same speed as in the first (accepted) answer

Answer (score 1):

I would extract the `id` and use it as key to an object. This way comparing for existance between the two will be much faster.

```
var id1 = arr1.reduce(function(p,v,i){p[v.id] = i; return p;}, {}),
    id2 = arr2.reduce(function(p,v,i){p[v.id] = i; return p;}, {});

for(key in id1){
   if (id2.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        var element1 = arr1[id1[key]],
            element2 = arr2[id2[key]];

        theFunction(element1.value1, element2 .value2);
   }
}
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/1ej0jxpq/2/

Comment: updated to use your preferred output method (*your function instead of console*)

Comment: Thanks; I tried both this and the first (accepted) answer, and they're about the same speed.  You did have a little buggy in there -- it was omitting the first element because this line: `if (id2[key]){` was reacting to 0 indexes incorrectly.  Changed it to `if (ids2[key] || ids2[key] === 0) {` and it worked.  Just FYI

Answer (score 0):

I think the slowest part of the loop will be the DOM manipulation. If you move that outside the loop, and just build a string in the loop, it should be much faster...

```js
var arr1 = [{'id':10,'value1':'a1'},
            {'id':11,'value1':'b1'},
            {'id':12,'value1':'c1'},
            {'id':13,'value1':'d1'},
            {'id':14,'value1':'e1'}];

var arr2 = [{'id':100000,'value2':'a2'},
            {'id':11,'value2':'b2'},
            {'id':100002,'value2':'c2'},
            {'id':100003,'value2':'d2'},
            {'id':14,'value2':'e2'}];

// create a string to build results
var out = '';
for (var i = 0, len1 = arr1.length; i < len1; i++) {
 for (var j = 0, len2 = arr2.length; j < len2; j++) {
  if (arr1[i].id === arr2[j].id) {
            // build results string in loop
   out += '<br />value1: ' + arr1[i].value1 + ', value2: ' + arr2[j].value2;
   break;
  }
 }
}
// append results to dom
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += out;
```

```html
<div id='out'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but "theFunction" in my _actual_ code does things that are MUCH more involved and time-consuming than what's in my example, and unfortunately that part can't be helped/optimized... (anymore...)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is kind of the same, but a more elegant solution:

```
arr1.forEach(function(e,i) {
    var same = arr2.filter(function(o, p) {
        var eq = o.id === e.id;
        if(eq) { arr2.splice(p, 1); } // remove used elements
        return eq;
    });

    // here 'same' is an array of objects with the same id, 
    // we don't know how big it is, but
    // at least the first position always has something        
    if(same.length) {
        console.log(e, ", ", same[0])
    }
})
```

Comment: Probably a bit slower though, which is what he's trying to avoid.

Comment: I was being polite. It will be slower because you're iterating the full `arr2` for every item in `arr1`. His original breaks the loop.

Comment: now it is a bit quicker, it removes used elements from `arr2`

Comment: But that causes a reindexing of the array from that point forward, which also has a decent bit of overhead, and the former elegance has vanished. If you want the functional approach, look into the ECMAScript 6 `.find()` method. That one breaks when a match is found. However, you'll still at best be back to the original algorithm used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming order is not important, you could take a different approach, by joining, sorting, then comparing adjacent values in single loop.

```js
var arr1 = [{'id':10,'value1':'a1'},
            {'id':11,'value1':'b1'},
            {'id':12,'value1':'c1'},
            {'id':13,'value1':'d1'},
            {'id':14,'value1':'e1'}];

var arr2 = [{'id':100000,'value2':'a2'},
            {'id':11,'value2':'b2'},
            {'id':100002,'value2':'c2'},
            {'id':100003,'value2':'d2'},
            {'id':14,'value2':'e2'}];

// join the two arrays, and sort them so you can loop through
// once comparing current to last value
arr1.concat(arr2).sort(function(a,b){
    return a.id !== b.id;
}).reduce(function(last, item){
    if(item.id === last.id){ theFunction(last.value1, item.value2) }
    return item;
}, {});

function theFunction(value1, value2) {
  var div = document.getElementById('out');
  div.innerHTML += '<br />value1: ' + value1 + ', value2: ' + value2;
}
```

```html
<div id='out'>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess the sort is doing much more than you need. I thought it would be decent anyway. Thanks for feedback.